# Merge the [grammar-constructions] tag into [grammar]

Tags: discussion, tags

I just found a new tag [grammar-constructions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-constructions) which seems rather redundant, so I think we should merge it into [grammar](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar), but I'll first post here in case anybody has any thoughts on the matter.

---

***Update***. Thanks everyone for the feedback. [grammar-constructions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-constructions) is now merged into [grammar](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar), and remains as a synonym, so that users searching for `construction` will find the [grammar](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) tag.

Comment: Definitely. That was bugging me the other day too.

Comment: I mentioned this in chat a year ago, though I forgot about it afterwards: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/511?m=53109213#53109213

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seconded! Going by this [excellent answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/73051/61125) grammar is "syntax and morphology", there is nothing under "grammar constructions" that couldn't go under grammar as construction questions are about syntax. But we also have a [syntax](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax) tag that serves a more specific purpose. I agree that [grammar-constructions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-constructions) is not necessary.